# How to map table variable name to tempdb table name?

Tags: sql-server

If I create a table variable:

```
    declare @work table (MyColumn varchar(50) null);
```

I can then see information about it in `tempdb.information_schema.tables` and `tempdb.information_schema.columns`:

```
    select * from tempdb.information_schema.tables;
```

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tempdb | dbo | #B641D0A5 | BASE TABLE |

```
    select * from tempdb.information_schema.columns; -- selected columns below
```

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tempdb | dbo | #B641D0A5 | MyColumn | 1 | varchar | 50 |

However, the information in tempdb does not map the temporary table name `#B641D0A5` to the table variable `@work`.

Querying the `tempdb.sys.*` tables yields similar information, and likewise does not map the table variable to the hexadecimal name.

Is there a way I can find that mapping? It is trivial if only one table variable is created and queried for in tempdb, but if multiple table variables are created in the same batch, finding the "correct" table information in tempdb is problematic.

Thanks!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298681/1186

Comment: (Also, out of curiosity, why a table variable instead of a #temp table? Also you should use `sys.tables`/`sys.columns` instead of the incomplete and problematic `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, imho.)

Comment: I'm modifying an existing procedure and found I need to compare the table variable's column information to another table's. The procedure uses table variables as temporary work areas (few columns and few rows). Want to make as few changes to the procedure as possible.


Also, the corresponding sys.* tables contained the same information as information_schema. Regardless of which set of meta tables are queried, no link between the table variable name and its name in tempdb could be found (in my informal searching).

Comment: As Aaron mentioned, Temp tables should work here just as well, if not more easily.

You can store the few columns and rows of your results as simply as 


SELECT columns
INTO #TempTableName
FROM Table
Where Condition



The sys.tables/columns recommendation is just to be more accurate and avoid any incomplete results being returned by using things like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

And here is another Aaron Bertrand link talking about why:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210629/why-shouldnt-information-schema-views-be-used-to-determine-the-schema-of-an-obj